# Would CurrentCellDityStateChanged() gets called internally?

Tags: c#, winforms

the events of the property window shows all the available event for the currently selected control. Assume current selection is `datagridview` `(dgv).` In `dgv` there is an event called `CurrentCellDirtyStateChaged()` and `CellValueChanged().` Assume I have NOT created the `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged()` event. In the event of a cell value changed, would this `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged()` get called internally? (note that I haven't created this event explicitly )

thus I want to know, **even I explicitly CREATE an event or NOT** the required events will get called internally when THOSE EVENTS occur on a control?

thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *create* an event. The event was already defined *by the control*. You can create an event *handler*. Each event can have multiple handlers and all of those will be called. Most likely, the control will check if handlers are attached to save some time in case there are none before calling any.

If the control is well written, it should function the same, regardless of event handlers attached.

Comment: yes I meant event handlers : ) so event handler attached or not internally the event gets called!

Comment: @AndrewMC Yes and no. If none are attached, it will likely by optimized away. But for all pratical purposes, why would you care if you did not attach one?

Comment: just wondered, when cell values changes it's according events must be called internally in order to save the changes to the Value property of the Cell?

Comment: No, that's not how it is done. The event is fired to *notify* you that it happend. The code is executed no matter if you want to be notified or not.

Comment: so if I don't add an event handler, compiler does not add event handler internally? if so "Value" property is updated by some other internal mechanism

Comment: Correct. The value is *always* updated by some internal mechanism, which in turn sees fit to notify you of it via event. You can attach a handler to the event if you want to be notified or you can just let the control do whatever it does and don't care.